# Как можно при помощи DirectShow получить спектрограмму звука?

Tags: directshow, аудио

Как можно при помощи DirectShow получить спектрограмму звука?

Буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть доступ к несжатому аудиопотоку, то для самого простого случая вам достаточно над выборкой произвести быстрое преобразование Фурье, результат которого уже и будет искомый спектр.

Comment: а несжатый аудио поток.. что он собой представляет на самм деле..?

Comment: Эмм - просто оцифрованный вид звукового сигнала - его амплитуда в численном представлении)

Comment: Тоесть это набор интов.. которые описывают положение графика в данный момент времени?

Comment: Ну, если вы про график звука - то да. Если вы построите график синусоидального звука - там будет график синуса. Если от пищалки - прямоугольники... Ну и так далее)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.. буду пытатся)

Comment: http://psi-logic.shadanakar.org/fft/fft.htm - про Фурье тут подробно расписано)

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг [эта ссылка](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/DSound_Spectrum.aspx) поможет?

Comment: спасибо.. но это DirectSound.. я покачто мучаю DirectShow.. а с DirectSound еще не встречался(

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но DirectShow это от слова Show.. он со звуком не работает..

Comment: Работает.. Он создан для удобного воспроизведения и обработки звука и видео.. Википедия так говорит.. да оно так и есть..